# Java regex extract text

Tags: regex

I have my string something like this:

```
<center>
    <a href="https://ec-media.sndcdn.com/fLwbjgKwn7Sl.128.mp3?f10880d3e4" class="expanded button" style="max-width:220px;" download>Download Track 2.9MB</a>
    <a href="https://chrome.google.com/" class="expanded button hide-for-small-only" style="max-width:220px;" >Add to Chrome</a>
    <a href="/" ><b><i>Download Another Track</i></b></a>
    <br /><br class="show-for-medium"/>
</center>
```

And I would like to extract the url inside href BUT IT SHOULD CONTAIN **.mp3**.

I am using this regex: **href=\"([^\"]*)\"** but it couldn't detect if it contains.mp3

How could I extract the `https://ec-media.sndcdn.com/fLwbjgKwn7Sl.128.mp3?f10880d3e4` ? I want to extract it by searching .mp3 then get the whole url.

Answer (score 0):

So include the string you're looking for:

```
 String pattern = "href=\"([^\"]*\\.mp3[^\"]*)\"";
```

Comment: You should add a `*`-repetition for the last character class.